# Get Specific data of relational entity from CoreData

Tags: ios, iphone, core-data, one-to-many, nsmanagedobject

I am having Country, State and City entities in my CoreData model. Here is the structure:

```
@interface Country : NSManagedObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * cId;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * title;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *states; // This will contain State object
@end

@interface State : NSManagedObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * sId;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * title;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *cities; // This will contain City object
@property (nonatomic, retain) Country *country;
@end

@interface City : NSManagedObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * cityId;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * title;
@property (nonatomic, retain) State *state;
@end
```

As you can see I have one to many relation between Country - State and State - City.

Now what I want is to fetch Country list with all states, but don't want city list associated with States.

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Country"];
[request setPropertiesToFetch:@[@"cId", @"title", @"states"]]; 
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *aryCategories = [gblAppDelegate.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

`setPropertiesToFetch` Setting this property allows to have only mentioned fields from the entity but how to set only sid and title for NSSet states which contain State object.

For getting city list I will send another request.
Please help me on this.

Comment: this might help http://geekanddad.wordpress.com/2014/02/14/core-data-efficient-fetching-of-portions-of-entities/

Comment: I'm confused, are you saying that you want to prevent City's from being fetched? Relationships are always faulted so they won't be fetched if you don't try and access them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need `propertiesToFetch`. This feature (which BTW needs the `NSDictionaryResultType`) is for special situations where you have lots of data and only need certain fields. This is definitely not necessary in your case!

Just fetch the `Country` objects. Core Data will *automatically* optimize to avoid fetching unnecessary data into memory.

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestsWithEntityName:@"Country"];
// consider sorting
NSArray *countryList = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];
```

You now have a country list. It contains also the states. To get the states of a particular country could not be simpler.

```
NSSet *states = country.states;
```

*NB: I think calling your to-one relationship from `City` to `State` "country" is problematic. I suggest renaming it to `state`.*

Comment: I tried this and it works, I know that I get fault data until I use `country.states`. What I wanted to know is is there any way by which I don't get even the fault data of state.cities when I get state loaded in memory?

Comment: You should not care about faults. It is done in the background and already optimized for you.